# Java game's float calculation not returning correct values

Tags: java, floating-point, game-physics

I'm developing a game using Java, but there's a bit of an issue with the calculations. I have velX and velY. When I press 'W', this happens:

```
if(currentKeys[i] == "W") {
    velX += accel * Math.cos(angle);
    velY += accel * Math.sin(angle);
}
```

This *should* accelerate the player in the correct direction. Then, when I call updateVelocity, I try to decay the velocity like so:

```
private void updateVelocity() {
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
    System.out.println("Velocity X = " + velX + " | Velocity Y = " + velY);
    velX = velX * deccel;
    velY = velY * deccel;
    System.out.println("Velocity X now = " + velX + " | Velocity Y now = " + velY);
}
```

accel = 2.5f;

deccel = 0.98f;

velX, velY, x, y are all floats.

And yet System.out.println prints this:

```
Velocity X = 1.8965478 | Velocity Y = 1.8243668
Velocity X now = 0.09482739 | Velocity Y now = 0.091218345
Velocity X = 1.8965478 | Velocity Y = 1.8243668
Velocity X now = 0.09482739 | Velocity Y now = 0.091218345
Velocity X = 1.8965478 | Velocity Y = 1.8243668
Velocity X now = 0.09482739 | Velocity Y now = 0.091218345
Velocity X = 1.8965478 | Velocity Y = 1.8243668
Velocity X now = 0.09482739 | Velocity Y now = 0.091218345
```

What *should* happen is this: **2.5 * 0.98 = 2.45**, which decays the velocity by a bit, then adds the acceleration again, and decays *that* velocity. I've made sure all of the variables involved are floats, but nothing has changed. Is System.out.println just not a function that returns accurate numbers?

**EDIT:** I've written out a snippet of code which should reproduce the problem. Use this to keep things concise:

```
float accel, deccel;
float x, y, velX, velY;
float angle;

public Player(float x, float y) {
    this.x = x;     // the player's x position
    this.y = y;     // the player's y position
    velX = 0.0f;    // how much the player's x position will change this frame
    velY = 0.0f;    // how much the player's y position will change this frame
    accel = 2.5f;   // accel is a value that multiplies against the cos and sin of the angle in order to provide a directional increase in velX and velY.
    deccel = 0.98f; // deccel is a percentage value used to decay the player's velocity
    angle = 0.0f;   // set angle to a radians value between 0 and (2 * PI)
}

// update is kept barebones, since we only care about updating the velocity every frame in this example
void update(){
    updateControls();
    updateVelocity();
}

void updateVelocity(){
    x += velX;
    y += velY;
    velX = velX * deccel; // you can also use velX (or velY) *= deccel, I used the long version for a sanity check
    velY = velY * deccel;
}

// normally, update controls would be passed a series of strings, representing keystrokes, to process input logic with. However, for simplicity's sake, I've left out the controls, and have slotted in what happens when the player presses 'W'
void updateControls(){
    velX += accel * Math.cos(angle);
    velY += accel * Math.sin(angle);
}
```

If you need any more material, just let me know.

Comment: Why is `accel` sensitive to `angle`, but `deccel` isn't?

Comment: Where are your variables velX and velY defined. They must be acessable to botth methods, otherwise you will use local copies, and nothing will change

Comment: @jr593 Java is not Python; if they were not accessible to both methods then the code wouldn't even compile. There would be no "local copies" created

Comment: @jr593 This is a 'Player' class which inherits from a 'GameObject' class. GameObject contains the angle, velX, velY, x, y, accel, and deccel variables, so the Player class is privy to all of them.

Comment: What about value of angle and velX,velY before that function? But if you shown value is from "velX,velY=0" then other part of your code is wrong since you got unreal values of X,Y

Comment: Is angle in radians?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Yes, the angle is in radians. I clamp it between 0 and 2 PI.

Comment: @Myszsoda angle is only changed when the player rotates, and is measured in radians (clamped between 0 and 2 PI). velX and velY start at 0, and increase by 'accel' (2.5f) whenever the player presses 'W'. I then call 'updateVelocity()' which does as described above (deccel is set to 0.98f).

Comment: Basically, your output is unreal. in the best case, both highest values of sin/cos(PI/2)*2.5~=1.77. Lowering/increasing value will increase value of respectively velX/velY. And you got both values higher than the 1.77. And I recreated your sample of code with velX,velY=0, some angles and output is correct. Something must be wrong somewhere else, everything here is correct

Comment: @Myszsoda How did you get ~1.77? I just ran 2.5 * sin(2 PI) through Google Calculator, and I can't get close to that value. The highest value I can get is ~2.48, by using 2.5 * sin(2 * PI).

Comment: I think creating an [mcve] would either make this question a lot clearer or else (IMO more likely) expose the actual source of the bug, which is probably not the code you've shown.

Comment: Dude, math... https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/38/Sine_cosine_plot.svg/500px-Sine_cosine_plot.svg.png    PI/2 is the max value you can get for both cos and sin at once. It is not "math lib error" or "float error"

Comment: Source of error is not here, I am sure of it

Comment: @DanielPryden thanks for the tip. I've provided a stripped down snippet of code that you should be able to run in Java with little trouble.

Comment: bug alert: `currentKeys[i] == "W"` will always be `false`. Use `currentKeys[i].equals("W")` instead

Comment: @Bohemian But currentKeys[i] == "W" is working fine; it returns false when I'm not pressing 'W' and true when I am. Is there an advantage to using .equals as opposed to == ?

Comment: @Andrew you must be assigning `"W"` to `currentKeys[i]` for that to work. It's brittle. `==` compares object references - ie it has to be *the same* String object for the comparison to be `true`. `.equals()` compares *values* - ie "has the same characters"

Comment: @Bohemian I didn't know that! My current code for input is still working, but I'll swap in .equals for safety. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewMoore: I just tried with your example and I couldn't reproduce. Can you provide a more complete example that actually outputs something, and show us what output you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of experimenting, step-tracing, and head-scratching, I found the cause. My game has a function where, when the player presses 'S', the ship decreases speed more quickly. So, when the player isn't pressing 'S', this happens:

```
if(!breaking) {
    deccel = 0.05f;
}
```

Since the default value of deccel was changed to 0.98f, that snippet of code should now be:

```
if(!breaking) {
    deccel = 0.98f;
}
```

Thanks for the help, everybody. I'm still getting better at coding and debugging, so it was all appreciated.

Comment: No, it should not be `0.98f`. It should be something like `defaultDeccel` that is declared once, initialized to `0.98f`, and used everywhere you need the default deccel.

Comment: You're right, that's the exact reason this problem came up in the first place. I'm thinking, from now on, if I have a value that changes, but eventually returns to a default value, I'm gonna store that default value as a const or a final.

Comment: Or you could go a stage further, and use only named constants in your code. Giving a constant a name documents what it is, as well as ensuring the same value is used everywhere.